# Twitter User Stream API - recursive call in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, twitter, recursion

The code below works only one time. I called the function inside the loop, but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
def graphRepresent(max_id)
  baseurl = "https://api.twitter.com"
  path    = "/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"
  query   = URI.encode_www_form(
    "screen_name" => "#{@name["screen_name"]}",
    "count" => 200,
  )

if max_id>0 then
  my_id   = URI.encode_www_form(
    "max_id" => max_id,
  )
  address = URI("#{baseurl}#{path}?#{query}&#{my_id}")
else
  address = URI("#{baseurl}#{path}?#{query}")
end

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new address.request_uri

def print_timeline(time_graph)
  # ADD CODE TO ITERATE THROUGH EACH TWEET AND PRINT ITS TEXT

  today_date = DateTime.parse("#{Date.today}")
  tf_date = today_date.strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')
  today_tweets = 0
  today_favorite = 0
  today_retweet = 0

  yesterday_tweets = 0
  yesterday_favorite = 0
  yesterday_retweet = 0

  week_tweets = 0
  week_favorite = 0
  week_retweet = 0


  month_tweets = 0
  month_favorite = 0
  month_retweet = 0

  index =0

  time_graph.each_with_index  do |gtweets, index|
    if gtweets["created_at"] >= Time.parse("#{Date.today}") then
      today_favorite += gtweets["favorite_count"]
      today_retweet += gtweets["retweet_count"]
      today_tweets += 1            
    end

   if gtweets["created_at"] >= Time.parse("#{Date.today.beginning_of_month}") then
     month_favorite += gtweets["favorite_count"]
     month_retweet += gtweets["retweet_count"]
     month_tweets += 1            
   end

   if gtweets["created_at"] >= Time.parse("#{Date.today.beginning_of_week}") then
     week_favorite += gtweets["favorite_count"]
     week_retweet += gtweets["retweet_count"]
     week_tweets += 1            
   end

   if gtweets["created_at"] >= Time.parse("#{Date.yesterday}") && gtweets["created_at"] < Time.parse("#{Date.today}") then

    yesterday_favorite += gtweets["favorite_count"]
    yesterday_retweet += gtweets["retweet_count"]
    yesterday_tweets += 1            
   end

   if index == 199 then
     puts " Done one function ----------------------------------------------------------#{index} "
     max_id = gtweets["id"]
     graphRepresent(max_id)
   end 
 end

  @tweets_today = today_tweets
  @favorite_today = today_favorite
  @retweet_today = today_retweet

  @tweets_yesterday = yesterday_tweets
  @favorite_yesterday = yesterday_favorite
  @retweet_yesterday = yesterday_retweet

  @tweets_week = week_tweets
  @favorite_week = week_favorite
  @retweet_week = week_retweet

  @tweets_month = month_tweets
  @favorite_month = month_favorite
  @retweet_month = month_retweet
end

puts "#{@tweets_week} Tweets in a Week :)"

http             = Net::HTTP.new address.host, address.port
http.use_ssl     = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

consumer_key ||= OAuth::Consumer.new "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
access_token ||= OAuth::Token.new session['access_token'], session['access_token_secret']

# Issue the request.
request.oauth! http, consumer_key, access_token
http.start
response = http.request request

# Parse and print the Tweet if the response code was 200
time_graph = nil
if response.code == '200' then
  time_graph = JSON.parse(response.body)
  print_timeline(time_graph)
end
end #Ending main Function

max_id=0

graphRepresent(max_id)
```